# Redundant data in query

Tags: mysql, sql, categorical-data

I have a sql query

```
SELECT DISTINCT cp.model,cp.quantity AS jumlah ,cp.product_id,cd.name AS category_1,cd.category_id AS id_category_1, cd2.name AS category_2,cd2.category_id AS id_category_2, cd3.name AS category_3,cd3.category_id AS id_category_3 
FROM cartproduct cp 
LEFT JOIN cartproduct_to_category ctc ON ctc.product_id=cp.product_id
LEFT JOIN cartcategory cc ON cc.category_id=ctc.category_id
LEFT JOIN cartcategory_description cd ON cd.category_id=cc.category_id
LEFT JOIN cartcategory AS cc2 ON (cc.category_id=cc2.parent_id)
LEFT JOIN cartcategory_description cd2 ON cd2.category_id=cc2.category_id
LEFT JOIN cartcategory AS cc3 ON (cc2.category_id=cc3.parent_id)
LEFT JOIN cartcategory_description cd3 ON cd3.category_id=cc3.category_id
WHERE cp.quantity > 0 AND cp.product_id=6
```

In the output there is a lot of data. 
[image: Output Query]

The real data from the table cartproduct_to_category is this

[image: cartproduct_to_category]

What is the solution to my problem?

Comment: Can you please describe the requirement in more detailed manner?

Comment: @srikanthr the results of the query are displayed on many data displayed when the correct data is the data that I love arrow indicator on the first picture, but the results of these queries still show data improperly.

Comment: Does you intend to fetch data related to first record of cartproduct_to_category table?

Comment: There are many products in one category, and I want to add a category, the category of sub 1, and more.

Answer (score 0):

```html
    SELECT DISTINCT cp.model,cp.quantity AS jumlah ,cp.product_id,cd.name AS category_1,
cd.category_id AS id_category_1, cd2.name AS category_2,
cd2.category_id AS id_category_2, 
cd3.name AS category_3,
cd3.category_id AS id_category_3 
 FROM cartproduct cp 
 LEFT JOIN 
( 
SELECT Distinct product_id FROM cartproduct_to_category  

    )cartproduct_to_category ctc ON ctc.product_id=cp.product_id


 LEFT JOIN cartcategory cc ON cc.category_id=ctc.category_id
 LEFT JOIN cartcategory_description cd ON cd.category_id=cc.category_id
 LEFT JOIN cartcategory AS cc2 ON (cc.category_id=cc2.parent_id)
 LEFT JOIN cartcategory_description cd2 ON cd2.category_id=cc2.category_id
 LEFT JOIN cartcategory AS cc3 ON (cc2.category_id=cc3.parent_id)
 LEFT JOIN cartcategory_description cd3 ON cd3.category_id=cc3.category_id
 WHERE cp.quantity > 0 AND cp.product_id=6
```

Please change your Query Like This.

Comment: this is same output . any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You are using Left Join, it keeps adding rows on the left table in each joins, to the right table. if you only need the intersection of data, use Inner Join.

Please note you are joining 3 tables on themselves though.